# PeopleResults.aspx page returns 404

Tags: search

I am in my "profile page".
I see a "find people" search box at the top navigation section of the page
I search for the first name of a known user
I get redirected to the PeopleResults.aspx page with a 404 error

I have not set up a crawl for search yet, is this related?

Comment: Same thing happens when I add a people search web part to a page.  How can I determine id search is configured properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that a search site has been setup and configured.  Once it is setup, you then need to set the path in the Site Collections that will use it.  You can do that by editing the search settings for the given site collection.

Comment: I created a new Enterprise Search Site and I did not change any of the configuration options.  Is that the page that needs a change?  I also went to my root directory and looked at Settings to view the Site Collection Administration section > search settings... the radio button is on the "Do not use custom scopes..." and the Site Collection search results page is "/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx".  I tried changing that to my Enterprise Search page: "My1stEnterpriseSearch/Pages/default.aspx" but I still get the 404 error.  I'm still a little green on knowing where to go, in which context etc..

Comment: OSSSearchResults doesn't use the regular results page.  I would validate the path, you may need to start it with a "/" to make sure it goes back to the root.  

Also, I would change the option to allow the custom scopes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and resolved it by:

Created and Enterprise Search site

In CA > Manage service applications (under Service Apps) > User Profile Service App > Setup My Sites > Preferred Search Center and entered:
http://[yourdomain:port]/[path to enterprise search site]/Pages/

When I search from My Sites I now go to 
https://sharepoint.whatever.com/sites/search/Pages/PeopleResults.aspx?k=find%20me

The way I found it was to look at the difference between the URL the Ent. Search used and what I had entered in "Preferred Search Center" field in the My Sites service app config.

Crawling is something different.