# People Search returns 404 on a clean install

Tags: search, 404, people-search

I have a clean install of SharePoint 2010. Normal search is working fine (It is hitting the url `/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=test&cs=This%20Site&u=http%3A%2F%2Faf007841`. When I use the people search I get a 404 page. The URL it is hitting is `/Search/PeopleResults.aspx?k=test`.

`PeopleResults.aspx` does not seem to be there.

Comment: This is the same question as this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/peopleresults-aspx-page-returns-404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a search center first, then in site collection settings (for your site from where you perform people search) set this search center URL (http://yoursite/search/pages - for example).

You may also need to check your User Profile Service - does it import users from AD correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You will also want to familiarize yourself with the search settings for your site collection.  If you go to Site Settings, Site Collection Administration and select Search Settings you will see the different settings available to you for pointing to the search center and how the scopes should behave.  If you are going to OSSSearchResults.aspx you are not going to have the full functinality available in Search.